# Ionic 2: Changes in data model not updated in UI until interaction with UI

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

**Q) Why are the changes in my data not shown on the UI, e.g. a list of items, but as soon as I interact with the UI they magically appear?**

For example, if I'm getting some data that is bound to a list and then updating that list like so:

```
this._LocalStorageService.getClients().then(
  (data) => {    
    this.clients = (data.res.rows.length == 1) ? <Client[]>JSON.parse(data.res.rows.item(0).clients) : [];
    this.showNoDataPresent = (this.clients.length == 0);  
  },
  (error) => {
    this._LogService.error(JSON.stringify(error.err));
  }
);
```

The `clients` list doesn't appear in the UI until I interact with the app, e.g. clicking the menu button, or focusing a search field.

Comment: I had a similar issue, and the problem was where I was executing the request. My advice is to avoid `ngOnInit`, `onPageWillEnter`, and `onPageLoaded` for any async calls that need to update the view. I had to use `onPageDidEnter()` to get the view to update after an on-load async call.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what `onPageWillEnter` and `ngOnInit` is for! This bug was confirmed related to a silent failure in angular 2.  I'm using `onPageWillEnter`/`ngOnInit` with absolutely no problems now, so you might want to re-visit them if you have any further issues.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have upgraded to beta.6 and follow the following guide  (because there are few required changes in addition to updating the dependencies in package.json)

1. Update the Ionic CLI to the latest version:npm install -g ionic@beta
2. If you're upgrading a project using Ionic 2.0.0-beta.3 or older check out the following guide first.
3. Remove the line import 'es6-shim' from app.ts/app.js.
4. Add es6-shim.min.js before angular2-polyfill.js in the index.html file:

   ```
     <script src="build/js/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
     <!-- Zone.js and Reflect-metadata  -->
     <script src="build/js/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
     <!-- the bundle which is built from the app's source code -->
     <script src="build/js/app.bundle.js"></script>
   ```
5. Update your package.json (do not copy&paste use these as a reference and update the ones in your file):

   "dependencies": {      "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",      "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
         "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.6",
         "ionic-native": "^1.1.1",
         "ionicons": "3.0.0-alpha.3",
         "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
         "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
         "zone.js": "^0.6.11"
       }
6. In your package.json update the version of ionic-gulp-scripts-copy to ^1.0.1.
7. From inside of your project's folder run npm install to install the new packages.
8. Check out the changelog149 for breaking changes and update your project accordingly.

Source : https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-projects-updating-to-beta-6/50049